# TFS - What is the best solution for check-in WCF service references?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I use Microsoft Team Foundation and my project works with WCF services. When I check-in my solution in the client-side then my service references goes to server and it makes problem and conflicts for others when they Get Latest version of my program. What is the best solution for check-in service references?

Comment: not sure who down voted it. But anyway, you should had specified what problem when saying "it makes problem".

Comment: why do your services references create conflicts for others?

Comment: @lockstock because we have different versions of service references

Comment: why do you have different versions of the services references?

Comment: @lockstock because I change my services and update my service references

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about a similar topic [getting the WSDL during builds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/giuliov/archive/2012/12/13/getting-web-services-wsdl-automatically-during-build.aspx), WSDL is the service contract in a platform independent form. Maybe it could be of help.